Подсказки IntelliJ IDEA
Как отключить данные подсказки, раньше висел значок copilot(предположу что тоже он) для вкл/выкл, однако сейчас нет


Это Full Line code completion
Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion > Machine Learning-Assisted Completion
Отключите флаг в Enable Full Line suggestions

